# BULK INSERT tab delimited data with missing value

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulk

I am trying to import a comma delimited data which is as follows.

```
5595,M,45,ABIQUIU,NEW MEXICO,132,EspanolaNM,40,AlbuquerqueHCS,.,NM,"ABIQUIU ,NM",324,1,1,0.1396

bulk insert Albuqurque from 'C:\AlbqurC.txt'
with
(
fieldterminator=',',
rowterminator='\n',
)
```

I am getting an error because there is a missing value "." after AlbuquerqueHCS

If I delete the missing value and replace that with a blank

```
5595,M,45,ABIQUIU,NEW MEXICO,132,EspanolaNM,40,AlbuquerqueHCS, ,NM,"ABIQUIU ,NM",324,1,1,0.1396
```

Import works fine,

Is there an option in sql BULK INSERT that will take care of missing values( "." ).... ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.` isn't a missing value. I'm supposing that the column type is incompatible with `.` values. You can open the CSV in another program and do a replace on that column.

Comment: you can also copy the table definition to a temporary table and change the offending column to `varchar`, insert into that table, then do a `select into` query on the real table where you substitute `.` with `NULL` (or another sensible value)

Comment: @BradAllred thanks Brad, I am getting this data from SAS, so I will check why . is generated. I have been doing the find and replace like you said, but I am worried that my csv file will be too big and I wont be able to open it in the first place to do a find and replace.          But your idea of importing this a Char and then replacing the . with a NULL sounds interesting I will try that.